# Matplotlib: How to recreate `6 petal` polar diagram

Tags: python, matplotlib

For an assignment, I have to recreate the following plot (including all labels and ticks):

[image]

This is what I have tried so far with my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nmax=101 # choose a high number to "smooth out" lines in plots
x = np.linspace(0,20,nmax) # create an array x
y_br = np.sin(3*x) # y for the bottom right subplot

fig = plt.figure()
ax4 = plt.subplot(224, projection = 'polar')
ax4.plot(x, y_br, 'tab:blue')
```

But if you were to run this yourself, this does not replicate the plot. What function could be used here and how can tick marks be changed in polar plots? Thanks in advance?

Comment: This is a variation of a [rose curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_%28mathematics%29). However, you can't get 6 petals with a single simple rose function. You'll either have to make two traces or do some trickery to your sine function (hint: notice how narrow these petals are compared to a normal rose function). To control the tick marks see [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html). Is this a coding problem or a math problem?